# c++ Circular includes (implementing component pattern)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, reference, include, components

Implementing the **Component** pattern in **C++**, I came upon a problem related with includes.



I have an `Entity` class, which has the following components: `Renderer`, `Physics` and `Collider`. They inherit from `Component`, which has a single virtual method `Component->update(elapsedTime)` and a reference to the `Entity` it belongs to.


Each time an `Entity` is updated, its components are updated too. As the components alter the `Entity`'s state, I thought it would be a good idea making them have a reference to the `Entity` they belong too (I could pass the `Entity` as a parameter in the `Component->update()` call but for performance I prefer not doing so).


Now I must include `Renderer`, `Physics` and `Collider` from `Entity`, and include `Entity` from `Component`. Luckily, `Entity` calls methods from the above but `Component` just stores a reference to `Entity`, so I should include normally `Renderer`, `Physics` and `Collider` from `Entity`, and forward declare `Entity` from `Component`. After doing so, I found a problem which I cannot solve or know how to investigate. So I tried the other way around, and other problems risen up.

- Including normally `Renderer`, `Physics` and `Collider` from `Entity`, and forward declare `Entity` from `Component`:

A class which includes `Entity` would complain saying that `Entity` is ambiguous. This is due to (I think) that class loading `Entity`, then loading its `Component`s which forward declare `Entity`. How can I forward declare `Entity` without having other classes complaining about this ambiguity?

- Including normally `Entity` from `Component`, and forward declaring `Renderer`, `Physics` and `Collider` from `Entity`:

In my `Entity->update()` method I do `this->collision->update()` which breaks, by saying that *`pointer to incomplete class is not allowed`*.

How can I solve this without changing my class structure or behavior?

Here are the files, using the first example (including the components and forward declaring `Entity` from `Component`:

`Entity.h`

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H

#define ENTITY_H

#include "Collision.h"
#include "Physics.h"
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "TextureRenderer.h"

using namespace Components;

namespace Entities
{
    class Entity
    {
        public:

            Entity();

            Collision* getCollision();

            virtual void update(float elapsedTime);

        protected:
            Collision* collision;
            Physics* physics;
            Renderer* renderer;
    };
}
#endif
```

`Entity.cpp`

```
#include "Entity.h"

namespace Entities
{

    Entity::Entity()
    {
    }

    Collision* Entity::getCollision()
    {
        return this->collision;
    }

    void Entity::update(float elapsedTime)
    {
        collision->update(elapsedTime);
        physics->update(elapsedTime);
        renderer->update(elapsedTime);
    }

}
```

`Component.h`

```
#ifndef COMPONENT_H

#define COMPONENT_H

namespace Components
{
    class Component
    {
        public:
            Component(Entity* entity);

            virtual void update(float elapsedTime) = 0;
        protected:
            Entity* entity;
        private:
            friend class Entity;
    };
}

#endif
```

`Component.cpp`

```
#include "Component.h"
#include "Entity.h"

namespace Components
{
    Component::Component(Entity* entity)
    {
        this->entity = entity;
    }
}
```

`Collision.h`

```
#ifndef COLLISION_H

#define COLLISION_H

#include "Component.h"

namespace Components
{
    class Collision : public Component
    {
        public:
            void collide(Entity* entity);

        protected:
            virtual bool collidesWith(Entity* entity) = 0;
    };
}

#endif
```

`Collision.cpp`

```
#include "Collision.h"

namespace Components
{
    void Collision::collide(Entity* entity)
    {
        if (this->collidesWith(entity))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

`Renderer.h`

```
#ifndef RENDERER_H

#define RENDERER_H

#include "Component.h"

namespace Components
{
    class Renderer : public Component
    {
        public:
            Renderer(Entity* entity);

            virtual void update(float elapsedTime) override;
    };
}


#endif
```

`Renderer.cpp`

```
#include "Renderer.h"

namespace Components
{
    Renderer::Renderer(Entity* entity) : Component(entity){ }

    void Renderer::update(float elapsedTime){}
}
```

And `Physics` is pretty much empty and I don't feel like adding it right now.


Thanks a lot



*I'm having way to much problems with includes. My code does a lot of double referencing for performance reasons, and each pair of classes accesses the methods of each other. C++ hates this, and defining which class should forward declare the other is a pain in the ass.*

Comment: Looks like complment.h can get by with just a forward declaration of `Entity`. Good reading on how to work around header dependencies in [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes).

Comment: Use Forward declaration.

Comment: Note that if I forward declare `Entity` in `Component` (as the files show), classes which include `Entity` have ambiguity problems

Comment: `Component.h` will probably be easiest to wrap your head around looking something like this: https://pastebin.com/DVvSwTqg TL;DR: Don't forget that `Entity` is inside a namespace.

Comment: Don't use `using namespace XXX;` in header.

Comment: @user4581301 Ok, I'll try that. Looks more clean.

Comment: @Jarod42 What should I use to include the namespace? Or should I do Namespace::Class everytime I include some class from another namespace?

Comment: You might use it in cpp, not in header. In header, that nullify the interest of namespace. Prepend with `XXX::`.